# after installing uwsgi, python will still error: No module named 'uwsgi'

Tags: python, python-3.x, uwsgi

I'm not exactly sure what is required to import uwsgi in python3. This issue has started happening very recently. I have web socket methods throughout my app that `import uwsgi`, it sounds like a fairly common module.

But after verifying that it was properly installed:

```sh
pip install uwsgi
DEPRECATION: Python 3.4 support has been deprecated. pip 19.1 will be the last one supporting it. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.4 won't be maintained after March 2019 (cf PEP 429).
Requirement already satisfied: uwsgi in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (2.0.18)
```

It seems as if I cannot use this module anywhere:

```
root@4a4d65e514ba:/usr/src# python 
Python 3.4.5 (default, Dec 14 2016, 18:54:20) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import uwsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'uwsgi'
```

Has the uwsgi module changed in recent months?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uwsgi is not a module it is applications server.
To use uwsgi module in your app, you should run your app with uwsgi.